# How to spawn ssh as a command in rust?

Tags: ssh, rust

I would like to run the ssh binary as a child of my small rust project.

The C# code would look something like this:

```cs
var info = new ProcessStartInfo("ssh", "user@192.168.0.1");
info.UseShellExecute = false;
var proc = Process.Start(info);
proc.WaitForExit();
```

I've got this far in rust. It runs other binaries like bash, cat, ls, echo just fine except ssh. (I tried using the absolute path of ssh as well.)

```rust
let mut child = Command::new("ssh").arg("user@192.168.0.1").spawn().unwrap();
let asd = child.wait().unwrap();
```

I've look into this [ssh2 crate](https://docs.rs/ssh2/0.9.3/ssh2/index.html) but it looks lot more work.

---

**Edit:**

So basically what happened is that somehow the built in vscode terminal thing doesn't like the bin being launched from rust but fine with everything else. (Maybe telnet client would fail similarly.)

Comment: Are you getting any errors/exceptions?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM None. Everything is excecated as it would with "ls" or any other bin.
If try to run "ssh_asd" it throws an exception but not with "ssh".

Comment: `ssh` works fine for me. Are you running your Rust program with a TTY? Also, what operating system are you on?

Comment: @Aplet123 WSL Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
So, it doesn't work in the built in vscode shell but works in windows terminal.